# App is stuck on splash screen after upgrading to Expo SDK 48.0.10

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen

I updated my Expo project to **SDK 48.0.10**. It works fine on test environments and Expo Go, but when I produce an APK and install it on my device, it gets stuck on the splash screen. I've tried many things but no luck yet.

Things to consider:

- App flashes one time and nothing happens
- `hideasync()` runs
- When I downgraded to SDK 47, it works fine
- Updated all packages and  Node version,
- Did everything from the Expo migration guide

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I updated some other dependencies, and now it is working again. I don’t exactly know which one, but I updated the dependencies to the latest versions, which are newer than the versions recommended by the Expo migration guide. I also updated the Babel version. I went to npm, searched for all package names, and checked that the versions were the latest.

Here are all of the dependencies that I am using and have updated:

```
"dependencies": {

    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "expo": "^48.0.10",
    "expo-dev-client": "^2.1.6",
    "expo-font": "^11.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.4.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same is happening to me. The app works perfect on expo go, but once the build is done, testing in the mobile phone is gets stuck in splash screen.
Any ideas?

In case it helps (it didn't help me) a user in Discord mentioned:
Juhis
—
02/05/2023 10:16
I was able to fix it. My issue was that react-native-reanimated was not included in babel.config.js as a plugin, I don't know but maybe this could help. Good luck!

I just don't know how to check which modules should be in babel.config.js

Extra update:
So! here it goes:  E  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGestureHandlerRootView" was not found in the UIManager. Seems like I was missing react-native-gesture-handler and somehow expo go was ignoring it. Now tried the app in TestFlight and is working!  It is really helpful to have Android Studio with the virtual device to see the log from the APK. Cheers!

Comment: I considered this solution, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Something did the trick for me. Important! Test the apk using android simulator to be able to see the logs. Not all show up in expo go sdk 48. My problem was here: here it goes:  E  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGestureHandlerRootView" was not found in the UIManager. Seems like I was missing react-native-gesture-handler and somehow expo go was ignoring it. Now tried the app in TestFlight and is working!  It is really helpfull to have Android Studio with the virtual device to see the log from the APK. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

if you want, you can downgrade to SDK version 48.0.0. The latest version, SDK 48.0.10, may have some bugs

Comment: did it nothing fixed